# WCF TimeoutException caused by maxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

We noticed that our application which uses netTcpBinding suddenly stopped working. After examining the event log on the server which hosts the service, I found the following warning (one of series of many):

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: TimeoutException 
>       Exception message: The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may
>   have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

To fix the issue, I had to increase the size of maxReceivedMessageSize by 10, so my new binding looks like this:

```
>  <netTcpBinding>
>     <binding name="largeBufferNetTcpBinding" listenBacklog="100" maxBufferSize="519730000" maxConnections="100"
>              maxReceivedMessageSize="519730000" portSharingEnabled="true">
>       <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="519730000"/>
>       <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
>       <security>
>         <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
>       </security>
>     </binding>
>     <binding name="defaultNetTcpBinding" portSharingEnabled="true"/>
>     <binding name="defaultNetTcpMexBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
>       <security mode="None"/>
>     </binding>      </netTcpBinding>
```

I don't understand how the maxReceivedMessageSize is related to the TimeoutException shown above. What can I do to troubleshoot this further and make the service more reliable?

Comment: Personally, I don't see how they are linked, unless you have an extremely slow network. Do you have any method tracing in your code that you can use?

Comment: We have tracing in our service, but it doesn't even get there, as the error is being thrown by WCF/.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what's going on in your client/service interaction based on the info in your question but here are some things to try:

First, change everything that you set to 519730000 back to the default values except maxReceivedMessageSize which should be set to something in the range of 2 - 3 MB (start at 2097152 & increase until that message size exception goes away).

If that doesn't work, keep the same settings I've suggested but change the config to `basicHttpBinding` instead of `netTcpBinding` in both the service and client for this test. If this binding change works then it's very likely you're not properly disposing of the WCF client instances (`ClientBase` or channels from `ChannelFactory`). `netTcpBinding` depends on sessions and if the client instances aren't disposed of correctly, your code isn't releasing TCP resources efficiently on both the service & client. BTW: wrapping the client instance in `using` is not the right way either because of the [funkiness of the WCF Dispose implementation](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidBarrett/archive/2007/11/22/117058.aspx).

If the calls still have timeouts, then you've pretty much eliminated bad TCP & client configuration and you should focus on the code performance of the service implementation.

Comment: I dug into out code and discovered that we were using "using{}" statements around the proxies in one method, while another was not trying to "close" the proxy at all. I hope this was the issue. I modified the methods with the try/catch/abort paradigm and will do more testing.

Comment: Great! I've found that using the `netTcpBinding` forces your client/service resource management code to be very clean because otherwise you run into problems like yours, kinda like proof of the pudding. I added a link to a post that discusses the WCF Disposable problems. Sorry I didn't add it initially, I had a meeting to run to. Thanks!